# How to convert all of datetime Column in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here's my DDL

```
    CREATE TABLE `MY_MODEL` (
        `FIELD2` timestamp ...
```

Here's my SQLAlchemy Model

```
class MyModel(Base):
    field1 = Column("FIELD_1", String)
    field2 = Column("FIELD_2", DateTime)
```

And I want converted value from all of DateTime Columns

Like this.

```
Class Base:
    def global_column_getter(model):
        for value in model.columns:
            if type(value) is datetime:
                value = str(value)
            return value
```

And it works like this expected.

```
m = MyModel()
m.field2 = "2000-01-01 00:00:00"  # str, not datetime
session.add(b) or session.flush(b) or session.refresh(b)  # all works fine

r = session.execute(some_statement)
assert type(r.field2) == str
```

Because my db server allow '0000-00-00' datetime. but python's datetime not allow that.

so when I select data, it raise python system error.

And I concerned about auto update commit. if I convert that type, does it committed auto?

How to do that?

I went over about SQLAlchemy validator, but it works with specific columns, not global.

---

**Edit**

my mistakes. it doesn't raise error but,

the Alchemy model returned, has different attribute type.

- "2000-01-01 00:00:00" -> datetime
- "0000-00-00 00:00:00" -> str

I want same type.

"0000-00-00 00:00:00" can not converted python datetime. so it must be str.

how to do that? Im checking up about sqlalchemy TypeDecorator now.

is there any other way like `global getter`?

Comment: "so when I select data, it raise python system error" - Please [edit] your question to show the complete stack trace, including the full error message.

Comment: @GordThompson Im sorry about my mistake :( I edit my question `edit`.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use a [TypeDecorator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types).

Comment: @GordThompson yes, I'm updating all of TIMESTAMP, DATETIME, TIME column's type with TypeDecorator now!!
I think there is no other way. thanks for comment :)